# Copy tables from sql server to db2

Tags: sql-server-2008, db2, migration

I have a few tables under a sql server database, most of the contents are INT or VARCHAR, two tables have image column. Now I wanted to copy these tables to DB2 10.1 LUW and zseries, and v7r1 on iseries, what is the best way to perform this data migration?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Import and Export Wizard might help

[sql server i&e wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Sql Server Integration Services(SSIS) to handle it more efficiently.
http://www.packtpub.com/article/mysql-data-transfer-using-sql-server-integration-services-ssis

Or

You can also use the BCP command